# How does JavaScript allow you to execute member functions without actually creating an object?

Tags: javascript, class

I came across some code that exports a class.

```
export default class RestaurantsDAO {
    static async injectDB(conn) {/definitions}
}
```

And it is imported as follows

```
import RestaurantsDAO from "./dao/restaurantsDAO.js"

PromiseObj.then( client =>{
await RestaurantsDAO.injectDB(client)
})
```

Comment: because it's static?

Comment: Since its a static method that's why it doesn't require to create an instance of it.
So in this way it will having singleton value, no matter from wherever you access it.

Comment: Notice that if this method is the only method in that `class`, it's a really bad pattern.

Comment: @Bergi There were more methods, i just removed all the implementation code and other functions to keep it simple for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static function is a member of the constructor function, not the prototype. Prototype members are accessed from an instance whereas static members are accessed directly from the constructor function, in this case the RestaurantsDAQ function.